# what is wrong with this quicksort code?

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am simply trying to implement Quicksort but its not working. The output comes out to be the same as the input and not the sorted array. i've tried using different inputs but the output is same.

```
  #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int partition(int a[],int start,int end)
    { int i,j;

         j=start;
        int pivot =a[end];
        for(i=start;i<end-1;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<=pivot)
            {
            swap(a[i],a[j]);        

            j++;
            }
        }
        swap(a[j],a[end]);
        return j;
        }
    void quicksort(int a[],int start,int end)
    {int j;
     if(start<end )
        {
        j =partition(a,start,end);
        quicksort(a,start,j-1);
        quicksort(a,j+1,end);
    }
    }


    int main()
    {  
    int a[20],start,end,i,n;
    cout<<"enter no . of elements"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin>>a[i];
    }
    end =a[n-1];
    start =a[0];
    quicksort(a,start,end);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { cout<<a[i];
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

kindly tell me where it is getting wrong?

Comment: I'm amazed this causes a logic error and not a memory access violation!

Comment: `quicksort` expects its `start` and `end` parameters to be indexes into the array, but what you are actually passing are values from the array: `end=a[n-1]; start =a[0];`.

Comment: Just a note, fixing `start` and `end` won't make it work correctly either. Giving it `1 2 3 4 5` as inputs will un-sort the sorted values.

Answer (score 1):

you define start and end as the **value** of the first and last element here:

end =a[n-1];
start =a[0];

then you say do nothing if the **value** of start is larger then the **value** of end here:

```
    if (start < end)
    {
        j = partition(a,start,end);
        quicksort(a,start,j-1);
        quicksort(a,j+1,end);
    }
```

therefore if the first value you enter is larger than the last one the function won't change any value.